# How do I convert a file path to a URL in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, url, image

Basically I have some code to check a specific directory to see if an image is there and if so I want to assign a URL to the image to an ImageControl.

```
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(photosLocation))
{
    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(photosLocation, "*.jpg");
    if (files.Length > 0)
    {
        // TODO: return the url of the first file found;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no method to do what you want; at least not directly. I'd store the `photosLocation` as a path relative to the application; for example: `"~/Images/"`. This way, you could use MapPath to get the physical location, and `ResolveUrl` to get the URL (with a bit of help from `System.IO.Path`):

```
string photosLocationPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(photosLocation);
if (Directory.Exists(photosLocationPath))
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(photosLocationPath, "*.jpg");
    if (files.Length > 0)
    {
        string filenameRelative = photosLocation +  Path.GetFilename(files[0])   
        return Page.ResolveUrl(filenameRelative);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't find the ResolveUrl member of HttpRequest in the documentation for any of the .Net versions. Are you using ASP.Net MVC?

Comment: @Fredrik As Jared has pointed out the HttpRequest object doesn't have this method. It can be found in the Page object or a web control object. Could you edit your answer to reflect this?

Answer (score 16):

this is what i use:

```
private string MapURL(string path)
{
    string appPath = Server.MapPath("/").ToLower();
    return string.Format("/{0}", path.ToLower().Replace(appPath, "").Replace(@"\", "/"));
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, here is it as an extension method on `Server` - `public static string MapUrl(this HttpServerUtilityBase Server, string path)`

Comment: Seems that this one is the right answer and cleaner ! plz upvote

Answer (score 11):

The problem with all these answers is that they do not take virtual directories into account.

Consider:

```
Site named "tempuri.com/" rooted at c:\domains\site
virtual directory "~/files" at c:\data\files
virtual directory "~/files/vip" at c:\data\VIPcust\files
```

So:

```
Server.MapPath("~/files/vip/readme.txt") 
  = "c:\data\VIPcust\files\readme.txt"
```

But there is *no* way to do this:

```
MagicResolve("c:\data\VIPcust\files\readme.txt") 
   = "http://tempuri.com/files/vip/readme.txt"
```

because there is no way to get a complete list of virtual directories.

Comment: There's a security issue. In general, one web application should not be able to do anything with the server outside its own web root. If that is really what you want, you could do it by querying the IIS metabase, something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710187/how-to-i-obtain-an-iis-virtual-directory-name-from-an-iis-metabase-path-in-c . But your web app would need to run with dangerously high privileges. If two web applications need to exchange files, better to implement services for them to do so.

Comment: Conceivably, the mapping might not be unique. Two virtual directories could be mapped to the same NTFS folder.

Answer (score 9):

I've accepted Fredriks answer as it appears to solve the problem with the least amount of effort however the Request object doesn't appear to conatin the ResolveUrl method.
This can be accessed through the Page object or an Image control object:

```
myImage.ImageUrl = Page.ResolveUrl(photoURL);
myImage.ImageUrl = myImage.ResolveUrl(photoURL);
```

An alternative, if you are using a static class as I am, is to use the VirtualPathUtility:

```
myImage.ImageUrl = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(photoURL);
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath + "ImageName";
```

Comment: Excellent answer! should have more up-votes.  In more detail, you need a switch to deal with the AppDomainAppVirtualPath, because if the website is on the root, the VirtualPath will be an empty string, so no slash needed before filename, if the VirtualPath is filled out, you need to add an extra slash.
        `string sVPath = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath;
        if (sVPath.Length > 0) sVPath += "/";
        string sCSSURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + sVPath + "myImage.jpg";`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is not the best way, but it works.

```
// Here is your path
String p = photosLocation + "whatever.jpg";

// Here is the page address
String pa = Page.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

// Take the page name    
String pn = Page.Request.Url.LocalPath;

// Here is the server address    
String sa = pa.Replace(pn, "");

// Take the physical location of the page    
String pl = Page.Request.PhysicalPath;

// Replace the backslash with slash in your path    
pl = pl.Replace("\\", "/");    
p = p.Replace("\\", "/");

// Root path     
String rp = pl.Replace(pn, "");

// Take out same path    
String final = p.Replace(rp, "");

// So your picture's address is    
String path = sa + final;
```

Edit: Ok, somebody marked as not helpful. Some explanation: take the physical path of the current page, split it into two parts: server and directory (like c:\inetpub\whatever.com\whatever) and page name (like /Whatever.aspx). The image's physical path should contain the server's path, so "substract" them, leaving only the image's path relative to the server's (like: \design\picture.jpg). Replace the backslashes with slashes and append it to the server's url.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I know there's no single function which does this (maybe you were looking for the inverse of [MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632.aspx)?). I'd love to know if such a function exists. Until then, I would just take the filename(s) returned by GetFiles, remove the path, and prepend the URL root. This can be done generically.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution seems to be to have a temporary location within the website that you can access easily with URL and then you can move files to the physical location when you need to save them.

Answer (score 0):

For get the left part of the URL:

```
?HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)
"http://localhost:1714"
```

For get the application (web) name:

```
?HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath
"/"
```

With this, you are available to add your relative path after that obtaining the complete URL.

Answer (score -2):

I think this should work. It might be off on the slashes.  Not sure if they are needed or not.

```
string url = Request.ApplicationPath + "/" + photosLocation + "/" + files[0];
```