# Open physical file on the server using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, hyperlink, download

I want to open a physical file on the server on HyperLink click.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyButton1" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("FullPath") %>' runat="server" Text="Open File" ></asp:HyperLink>
```

"FullPath" is like "E:\PINCDOCS\Mydoc.pdf"

Currently in Chrome i'm getting the error.

> Not allowed to load local resource:

Can this be done or any other alternative solution?

Comment: Use a linkbutton; add event handler for the button; open the file on the server-side (use `Server.MapPath method`); then stream as pdf. Better, if possible, copy that file in your static resource directory and use normal hyperlink.

Comment: to let client download a file you need a url,first you need to convert your server local path to a url
here is a link to do that
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007/how-do-i-convert-a-file-path-to-a-url-in-asp-net

Answer (score 2):

The physical file should be located within an IIS Web Site, Virtual Directory or Web Application.  So you'd need to create a virtual directory to E:\PINCDOCS.  See here for instructions: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172138

Then in your code behind you can use code like: http://geekswithblogs.net/AlsLog/archive/2006/08/03/87032.aspx to get a Url for the physical file.

Comment: Also, if you're on the same network as the server you could simply use the network name:  ie: \\servername\e$\PINCDOCS\Mydoc.pdf and then you don't have to mess w/ IIS.

Answer (score 0):

```
//SOURCE
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyButton1" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%#ful_path(Eval("")) %>' runat="server" Text="Open File" ></asp:HyperLink>//ful_path is c# function name

//C#:
protected string ful_path(object ob)
{
    string img = @Request.PhysicalApplicationPath/image/...;
    return img;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set the NavigateUrl to FullPath, Chrome will see the link local to the user machine who is accessing the site and not the server itself.

So, you always need to make the URL for any hyberlink to be in the form of //someURL or http://someurl

In your case, you have to remove the `NavigateUrl` and add a `OnClick` handler, and inside the handler, you will read the file using the FileStream and write the file contents to the response stream then flush it

example of the click handler:

```
context.Response.Buffer = false;
context.Response.ContentType = "the file mime type, ex: application/pdf";
string path = "the full path, ex:E:\PINCDOCS";

FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
int len = (int)file.Length, bytes;
context.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", len.ToString());
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
Stream outStream = context.Response.OutputStream;
using(Stream stream = File.OpenRead(path)) {
    while (len > 0 && (bytes =
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        outStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
        len -= bytes;
    }
}
```