# How to change path location of image from a folder to another

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some pictures in `path/TempFolder` after clicking on `AddButton` I want to change their locations one by one to `path/Images` and change their names 
any idea?

Comment: Did you try anything? Some code example would be nice..

Comment: Yes I've searched but most of them are talking about changing file name only

Comment: I found this link but it does not work for me 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007/how-do-i-convert-a-file-path-to-a-url-in-asp-net)

Comment: Search for "C# move file"! Google is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS has some documentation on how to achieve this. Have you tried the solutions presented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx)?

Edit: I've copied the SampleMove function from the site for future posterity here.

```
// Simple synchronous file move operations with no user interface. 
public class SimpleFileMove
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string sourceFile = @"C:\Users\Public\public\test.txt";
        string destinationFile = @"C:\Users\Public\private\test.txt";

        // To move a file or folder to a new location:
        System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);

        // To move an entire directory. To programmatically modify or combine 
        // path strings, use the System.IO.Path class.
        System.IO.Directory.Move(@"C:\Users\Public\public\test\", @"C:\Users\Public\private");
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds good , what I was looking for is copying image file and deleting previous one

Answer (score 1):

You can use `File.Move` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.io.file.move.aspx)) method:

```
foreach (var item in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\TempFolder"))
{
    string name = new System.IO.FileInfo(item).Name;
    string newName = name.Insert(name.IndexOf("."), "_new");
    System.IO.File.Move(item, System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Images", newName));
}
```