# Image from PostBack not showing in asp.Net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, image, postback

i have this issue with a list of images:

in the red circle is an example with a broken link.
my issue is in the blue circle, where calling correctly my codebehind method and having the correct src associated with every image, the image it is not shown.

Any ideas please? 
[image]

asp.net:

```
<asp:ListView ID="Screenshots" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul class="inner" style="display: inline;">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />    
        </ul>                
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:Image src='<%#Eval("Source")%>' HeaderText="Image"   ID="Image1" runat="server" class="col-xs-6 showgameinfo" style="width:50%"/>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

c# :

```
public class Screens
{
public Screens(string url)
{
    this.url = url;
}

private string url;
public string Source
{
    get { return url; }
    set { url = value; }
}
}
List<Screens> ListToReturn = new List<Screens>();

foreach (FileInfo foundFile in filesInDir)
{
    ListToReturn.Add(new Screens(foundFile.FullName));
}
Screenshots.DataSource = ListToReturn;
Screenshots.DataBind();
```

Comment: Did you inspect the resulting HTML to see if the `src` points to the correct location?

Comment: what's the source of image?  database? or any folder?

Comment: @mason: yes, the src is the correct one.

Comment: @achan: it is folder. i get it like this : Server.MapPath(MyDir)

Comment: And if you copy the src attribute you end up with on the client, and paste it directly into your browser, do you see the image? What does your browser's network tab on the developer tools tell you about when it tries to load the image?

Comment: this is what i get from the developer tool ::       <img class="col-xs-6 showgameinfo" id="MainContent_Screenshots_Image1_0" style="width: 50%;" src="D:\Www\DiverseMechanics\DiverseMechanics\Content\themes\base\images\InterLife\Screen1.jpg" headertext="Image"/>

Comment: i can see the image in the browser if i type directly in the addr bar

Comment: Images should not have absolute file paths (e.g. `C:\blah\blah.jpg`). There is too much to explain in a comment, but look into using virtual paths instead (`/Content/Themes/base/images/InterLife/Screen1.jpg`). The reason you can see the file when you browse directly is because browsers are capable of loading files directly from your local computer. However, that could never work when you deploy your site, unless you only ever plan to run on localhost or you expect every one of your users to have the path `D:\Www\ ...`, and even then security will not allow the image to load, as you've seen.

Comment: See the following for how to convert your file paths: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007/how-do-i-convert-a-file-path-to-a-url-in-asp-net.

Comment: @ pep: this is happening on localhost. i resolve the path using : Server.MapPath(MyDir)

Comment: It seems the postback is returing a corrupt string: Try selecting the directory /Interlife/ in the string i copypasted before. You cannot select all the word 'Interlife' because there seem to be some exra chars injected!!!! What is this?

Comment: if you're still using physical paths in an image then the path is going to look like this `C:\foo\bar\pic.jpg` the problem being `\ ` is a special character; usually used as an escape character or for things like `\n` or `\t`. So it's feasible that it works first time by then postback is trying to process this. 

Use virtual paths otherwise it'll not work when it goes into a live environment!